# Trying to identify an anime film with a throne room and a giant robot facing it

Tags: story-identification, anime

I have this very faint memory from my early childhood which intrigued me for a long time.

I remember a scene from an anime film. The animation style of animation is Ghibli-like. There was a scene with a throne room in the European style, and the interior was mostly red, with many cushions. I have a feeling that this throne room was either in a giant aerial city-like structure, or in a giant robot which was facing the aforementioned structure (the robot was certainly there). Someone was piloting the robot, maybe from that very throne room. I watched this film somewhere between 2003 and 2008.

That's all I remember. I've been trying to identify this film for a long time, and I suspected that it was *Castle in the Sky*. I've rewatched snippets of it, but thus far I haven't been able to find a scene which would correspond with my memory, so I doubt that's the correct film.

Some internet surfing provided me with this image, which is similar to my memory:
[image]

Comment: Ghibli like, as in, "old Japanese animation style"?

Comment: @Clockwork Yep, though I think there is notable diversity even in that niche. For example, the animation style of Macross is way different than that of Ghibli. My memory suggests a more Ghibli-like animation style.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. When I think about "old anime", my head thinks about stuffs like 90s Sailor Moon (which I never watched), which is also different from Ghibli.

Comment: Middle age and mecha... Does [Visions of Eskaflowne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vision_of_Escaflowne) ring any bells?